# How to highlight without one rule breaking another (font-lock-add-keywords)

Tags: font-lock

I have 2 rules and the second one highlighting text disables the first...

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("^rtfm .*$" 0 '(:foreground "red"))))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("'.*'"      0 '(:background "OrangeRed"))))
```

rtfm ... works

and 'this' works

but when I use them together only the second works.

rtfm whatever but then 'xx' and now only 'xx' is highlighted

This maybe sloppy, any tips are appreciated. (quote matching simplified here)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("^rtfm .*$" 0 '(:foreground "red"))))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("'.*'"      0 '(:background "OrangeRed") 'keep)))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Search-based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html) - look for **`keep`**:

> **`(MATCHER . SUBEXP-HIGHLIGHTER)`**
>
> In this kind of element, `SUBEXP-HIGHLIGHTER` is a list which
> specifies how to highlight matches found by `MATCHER`.  It has the
> form:
>
> ```
>      (SUBEXP FACESPEC [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])
> ```
>
> The `CAR`, `SUBEXP`, is an integer specifying which subexpression of
> the match to fontify (`0` means the entire matching text).  The
> second subelement, `FACESPEC`, is an expression whose value specifies
> the face, as described above.
>
> The last two values in `SUBEXP-HIGHLIGHTER`, **`OVERRIDE`** and `LAXMATCH`,
> are optional flags.  If `OVERRIDE` is `t`, this element can override
> existing fontification made by previous elements of
> `font-lock-keywords`.  If it is **`keep`**, then each character is
> fontified if it has not been fontified already by some other
> element.  If it is `prepend`, the face specified by `FACESPEC` is
> added to the beginning of the `font-lock-face` property.  If it is
> `append`, the face is added to the end of the `font-lock-face`
> property.

If you want both faces used for the text that both regexps match then use `prepend` or `append` instead of `keep`. That will combine the OrangeRed background with the Red foreground. (It's not clear from your question just what behavior you really want.)

Comment: Permutations and combinations...  emacs -q many many times.  If regexps matching overlap... it does not work.  Maybe I need a matching function that can go back to beginning of line (where other matches may have already occurred).  Thank you for the help, the documentation for font-lock-add-keywords does refer to font-lock-keywords that documents all that (what you pasted above).

Comment: This makes both work... but not when overlapping.  It does not do foreground AND background (when overlapping) -- (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("^rtfm .*" 0 '(:foreground "red")   )) 'keep)
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("'.*'"  0 '(:background "green") )) 'keep)

Comment: If you want to combine the faces you can use `append` or `prepend`, just as @Drew write in his answer.

Comment: @Lindydancer : do I understand it right that without clear integer based priorities append/prepend will work (does it? have you tested it?) for maximum of three different overlapping faces: prepended properties applied first, than already before added properties (middle of the list), then append as third will be applied to the final outcome? Why not provide an answer with an example code and an image demonstrating how it works and proving that it works? Too much effort?

Comment: @Drew it appears clear to me that OP wants in the overlapping area red foreground with OrangeRed background and in not overlapping areas only one the properties for the text. How does it come that you state *(It's not clear from your question just what behavior you really want.)*?

Comment: @Claudio, yes, I have tested it several times. In fact, I've written several packages and a suite of tools for font-lock where I've used this extensively. An answer like you suggested would have a pedagogical value, feel free to write one.